# Shell scripting question

Tags: shell-script

This Linux  program is supposed to print 0 to 4. But I'm unable to find error in this code.

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0

while [ $a -lt 5 ]
do
    echo $a
    a='expr $a + 1'
done
```

When I try to run it, it says 'Line 5: [: too many arguments'.

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 4):

You have use to backtick quotes for command substitution

```
a=`expr $a + 1`
```

Comment: Or better now adays is `$(...)` notation

Comment: @Eric Renouf Is this portable?

Comment: Yes, it's specified as part of the POSIX shell command language: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1 apparently yes, and `$(...)` is better practice because it makes nesting clearer (whereas backticks need escaping for nesting).

Answer (score 2):

I've provided three examples, first two are with `while` loops and the third is with an `until` loop. The first example uses very close syntax to your original, the third is a bit more complex as it uses dynamic settings for counter maximum and an array for iterating though words (space separated arguments) passed one at a time. Now these are *simple* examples and intended to only answer your direct questions in the scripting language of Bash if you want more advanced examples see the link attached to a script I'm maintaining on GitHub for examples of nested loops among other tech-wizardry.

## Example one

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
let _counter=0
let _max="5"
while [ "${_counter}" -lt "${_max}" ]; do
    echo "${_counter}"
    let _counter=++
done
unset _counter
unset _max
```

### Running example one example

```
./example_one.sh
1
2
3
4
5
```

## Example two

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_arr_args=( "${@}" )
let _counter=0
let _max="${#_arr_args[@]}"
while [ "${_counter}" -lt "${_max}" ]; do
    echo "${_arr_args[${_counter}]}"
    let _counter=++
done
unset _counter
unset _max
```

### Running example two example

```
./example_two.sh "$(seq 1 5)"
## same output as example one
```

## Example three (bonus)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_arr_args=( "${@}" )
let _counter=0
let _max="${#_arr_args[@]}"
until [ "${_counter}" = "${_max}" ]; do
    echo "${_arr_args[${_counter}]}"
    let _counter=++
done
unset _counter
unset _max
```

### Running example three example

```
./example_three.sh "$(seq 1 5)"
## same output as example one
```

#### Notes for new Bash script writers

- look up built-in variables/arrays and substitutions rules; it'll save you time, effort, and from unneeded piping to other programs.
- look up `shellcheck` it's available in most distributions, and in source form from it's authors, and is integrated into Code Climate with GitHub.
- as eluded to above [here is the link](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Perinoid_Pipes/blob/master/Paranoid_Pipes.sh) to an example of a script that makes use of both looping types shown above as well as auto code checking. However, the scripts' intention is well beyond the scope of answering the above question so search for "while" & "until" to find the relevant functions that use these calls.
- `bash` **!=** `sh` there are similarities but they're different, personally I find bash to be the better choice because it's less likely to bugger-up if given a sh script where as shell will do odd things with bash syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the string `'expr $a + 1'` to a.  That's not likely what you want.  Just change single quotes to backticks and it will work:

```
a=`expr $a + 1`
```

The above should answer your question. Below is some additional thoughts:

If your `/bin/sh` implementation is Bash, you could also consider using `$(...)` instead of backticks.  This has several advantages: it avoids typographic confusion between the single quote and the backtick, the `$(...)` form can be nested, and each nesting is in its own quoting context (so you can do things such as:

```
variable="$(somecommand -o "$file")"
```

Here is another implementation:

```
#/bin/bash

declare -i a=0
while [[ $a -lt 5 ]]; do
   echo $a
   ((a++))
done
```

Note that `sh` is not an implementation. So, to answer your question safely, we'd need to know if your intention includes POSIX portability, or if you are interested in a particular implementation such as `Bash`, `dash`, `tcsh`, etc.

Comment: `$(...)` is POSIX, it will work in any POSIX shell (so the POSIX `sh` of any system, most of the time found in `/bin`), not just `bash` `$((...))` arithmetic expansion is also POSIX.

Comment: @ValentinB. `$(...)` is POSIX but not Bourne. Every system will have a `sh` where that works but not necessarily in `/bin` like on Solaris 10 and older where `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell (an ancient, non-POSIX shell), and the standard shell is in `/usr/xpg4/bin`